# how can i print roc_auc_score in the terminal using jupiter notebook?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science, random-forest

*Hello,
I use python whith jupiter notebook,When i launch the training whith Random forest, i want to print the sklearn.metrics roc_auc_score in the terminal, it didn't work and i doesn't understand why,i put in comment the differents ways to arrive to the result but any works ! I really apreciate if someone could help me. Thanks !*

```
elif clf == 'rndforest':

# No validation data in rnd forest
x_train = np.concatenate((x_train, x_valid))
y_train = np.concatenate((y_train, y_valid))

model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=int(clf_params['n_estimators']),
                               max_features=clf_params['max_features'])
model.fit(pipe_vect.transform(x_train), y_train)

datetoday = datetime.today().strftime('%d-%b-%Y-%H_%M')
model_name_save = abspath(os.path.join("models", dataset,  name_file + '-' + vect + reduction + '-rndforest'\
                               + datetoday + '.pickle'))
print("Model d'enregistrement : ", model_name_save)
#auc_score = roc_auc_score(x_train, y_valid)
#print('Performance du modèle :', auc_score)
#prediction = model.predict_proba(x_train)       
#print(roc_auc_score(y_train, prediction))
#print('ROC AUC score :', roc_auc_score(y_test, preds_evaluate[:, 1]))
#print([tolist(t) for t in x_test])
#prediction = model.predict_proba(x_test)       
#print(roc_auc_score(y_test, prediction))


if not(args.modelname is None):
    print("test1",args.modelname)
    with open(args.modelname, 'wb') as f:
        cloudpickle.dump(model, f)
else:
    print("test",model_name_save)
    with open(model_name_save, 'wb') as f:
        cloudpickle.dump(model, f)
```

Comment: What are above lines how you are deciding if the method is random forest

Comment: i decid it in an another file, above the line there is two another model ( bert and rnn) that can be used, but it's not the case, thanks for your answer btw

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal working sample we can work with? What happens in the line "auc_score = roc_auc_score(x_train, y_valid)" ? Does it compute?

Comment: @KimTang yes it compute, what do you need ? i can give you the entire code

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari do you need more informations ?